# Navigate into Listbox zk with radio component

Tags: listbox, radio-button, zk

I have this `Listbox`in ZUL page :

```
<listbox id="lstboxResult">
    <listhead sizable="true">
        <listheader label="Editore" />
        <listheader id="lstAzienda" />
    </listhead>
</listbox>
```

And a `ListitemRender` :

```
public void render(Listitem listitem, Object data, int index) throws Exception {
    final String o = (String) data;
    if (!o.equals("")) {
        addListcell(listitem, String.valueOf(o));
        addRadiogroup(listitem);
    }
}

private void addListcell(Listitem listitem, String value) {
    Listcell lc = new Listcell();
    Label lb = new Label(value);

    lb.setParent(lc);
    lc.setParent(listitem);
}


private void addRadiogroup(Listitem listitem) {
    Radio radAla = new Radio("Label1");
    Radio radPeg = new Radio("Label2");
    Radio radRw = new Radio("Label3");

    Radiogroup rg = new Radiogroup();
    radAla.setRadiogroup(rg);
    radPeg.setRadiogroup(rg);
    radRw.setRadiogroup(rg);
    radAla.setParent(rg);
    radPeg.setParent(rg);
    radRw.setParent(rg);

    Listcell lc = new Listcell();
    rg.setParent(lc);
    lc.setParent(listitem);
}
```

How can get data from listbox setting Label value in list cell and checked value?
The second column contains 3 radios and each represent a choice. I'd like to save these choices in the database. I need a POJO to save the label and the checkbox choice for each row.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a small object in your list model instead of `String`. When the radios are checked, you save the choice in that object. Then you can save it later.

Look at this example:

```
lstboxResult.setModel(new ListModelList<>(Arrays.asList(new MyObject("1"), new MyObject("2"))));

lstboxResult.setItemRenderer(new ListitemRenderer<MyObject>()
{
    @Override
    public void render(Listitem listitem, MyObject data, int index)
        throws Exception
    {
        Listcell lc = new Listcell(value);
        lc.setParent(listitem);

        Radio radAla = new Radio("Label1");
        Radio radPeg = new Radio("Label2");
        Radio radRw = new Radio("Label3");

        Radiogroup rg = new Radiogroup();
        radAla.setRadiogroup(rg);
        radPeg.setRadiogroup(rg);
        radRw.setRadiogroup(rg);
        radAla.setParent(rg);
        radPeg.setParent(rg);
        radRw.setParent(rg);

        Listcell lc = new Listcell();
        rg.setParent(lc);
        lc.setParent(listitem);

        rg.addEventListener(Events.ON_CHECK, e -> {
            data.setSelectedIndex(rg.getSelectedIndex());
            data.setSelectedLabel(rg.getSelectedItem() != null ? rg.getSelectedItem().getLabel() : null);
            System.out.println(data.getLabel() + " " + data.getSelectedIndex() + " " + data.getSelectedLabel());
        });
    }
});

private static class MyObject
{
    private String label;
    private int    selectedIndex = -1;
    private String selectedLabel;

    public MyObject(String label) { this.label = label; }

    public String getLabel() { return label; }
    public int    getSelectedIndex() { return selectedIndex; }
    public void   setSelectedIndex(int selectedIndex) { this.selectedIndex = selectedIndex; }
    public String getSelectedLabel() { return selectedLabel; }
    public void   setSelectedLabel(String selectedLabel) { this.selectedLabel = selectedLabel; }
}
```

Now you can use the model to read the chosen radios from the `MyObject`s and do whatever you want with them.